# How to get decimal ordered list inside an ordered list in HTML

Tags: html

Need a decimal kind of listing for inner ordred List as

```
1. acsdv dfdfsf
  1.1 fasffaf
  1.2 wfwe  trtt werwr wr
```

Please provide suggestions if any. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply nest ul tags inside each other like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li>1.2</li>
    <li>1.3</li>
  </ul>
<li>2</li>
  <ul>
    <li>2.1</li>
    <li>2.2</li>
    <li>2.3</li>
  </ul>
<li>3</li>
  <ul>
    <li>3.1</li>
    <li>3.2</li>
    <li>3.3</li>
  </ul>
```